# NSDate creating a memory leak

Tags: ios, nsdate

I was already browsing through the questions alreaded posted and there were a lot of hints I tried to work with. Unfortunately I don't get the issue solved.

I simply have the following code:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
self.timestamp = date;
[date release];

[pool release];
```

But still there is a memory leak at the allocation line of NSDate. I tried it without the AutoreleasePool, I tried using drain instead of release for the pool, I even tried to use the static NSDate date methode. But I do not get rid of the memory leak.

I still don't get it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write only

```
self.timestamp = [NSDate date];
```

instead of given code block,it will work without leak.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. When profiling the code for memory leaks I still do get a 100.0% at the line then.

Comment: How is the timestamp property set up in your class ?

Comment: @Peter Osburg, Please tell me one thing what is the Datatype class of timestamp?????

Comment: timestamp is an NSDate *, as well. And declared as nonatomic, retain

Answer (score 1):

is `[timestamp release]` in your `dealloc` implementation? IE:

```
-(void)dealloc {
  // ... your other retained property/ivar releases ... //
  [timestamp release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, if you're running in a standard iOS project, you shouldn't need to set up an `NSAutoreleasePool` of your own (unless you're in a tight loop or a thread implementation).

Comment: Yes it is. And when I do the profiling I see the memory leak at the initialization of the date. That is why I am so highly confused. Could it be a problem in the SDK?

Comment: I would expect that the leak shows there because that is where the leaked object is allocated. It's not necessarily where you need to be doing something different.

Comment: Are you assigning anything directly to the `timestamp` ivar anywhere without releasing it first? Anything along the lines of `timestamp = [NSDate someKindOfNSDate];` that isn't preceded by a `[timestamp release];` call could cause a leak that would trace to your alloc.

Answer (score 0):

Memory Management in ObjectiveC for iOS is just reference reference counting. If you find ["Apple's Mem Management a bit daunting"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) then try this - [**"Simple Memory Management Tools for Cocoa"**](http://www.stepwise.com.sharedcopy.com/Articles/Technical/b57ca071a8e1e903044f18fa51db58d4.html)